# Dynamic background-image in MVC 4 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, background-image

I am trying to pick a random background-image for my MVC application. Inside my _Layout.cshtml I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var background = ['url("~/Content/images/image1.jpg")',
            'url("~/Content/images/image2.jpg")',
            'url("~/Content/images/image3.jpg")',
            'url("~/Content/images/image4.jpg")',
            'url("~/Content/images/image5.jpg")'];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        PickRandomBackground();
    });

    function PickRandomBackground() {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        $('html').css('background-image', background[index])
    }
</script>
```

What ends up happening is that the image cannot be found. My site.css is located in the Content folder and if I define the image the following way there:

```
html {
    background-image: url("images/image1.jpg");
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then it correctly finds it, however if I do the same definition inside my javascript (`.css('background-image', 'url("images/image1.jpg")`) it doesn't. I am running out of ideas so please help me with this.

Comment: You do realize that's not what you actually have in your array, yeah? `~/Content/images/image1.jpg` and `images/image1.jpg` are not equivalent

Comment: See the answer by Adil, the ~ only works on server-side code.  It means nothing in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give path without `~`

```
url("/Content/images/image1.jpg")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. I guess I'm too used to webforms thus the '~'

Comment: You can also write .net code in your javascript sorta like `var baseUrl = "<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>".replace(/\/$/, '');` and then you define your URLs as such:  `'url("' + baseUrl + '/Content/images/image1.jpg")'`

Answer (score 6):

your background array is composed in a wrong way. In .cshtml file it should look like this:

```
var background = ['@Url.Content("~/Content/images/image1.jpg")',
    '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/image2.jpg")',
    '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/image3.jpg")',
    '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/image4.jpg")',
    '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/image5.jpg")'];
```

This way Url.Content(...) function will resolve path into correct string. Check what is rendered on the page in browser.

Ahh, and then you can wrap in with 'url()' for css.

```
$('html').css('background-image', 'url(' + background[index] + ')')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add a css class for each background image then use:

```
$('html').attr('class', 'image4');
```

...to change the background image.